# как изменить начало graph editor blender2.82

Tags: blender

У меня есть проект. Этот проект выполнен по видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pOz-N2p4xs
Хотел бы что бы у меня получилось примерно так как в первой части этого видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4ICFmAr_DQ&t=24s
То есть до текста. Что бы это сделать мне нужно отсрочить начало graph editor. Каким способом можно это реализовать? 
Вот скриншот [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика работы с кривыми в Graph Editor аналогична общей практике работы с кривыми. Выдели нужные кривые (или сегменты), нажми G и перемести на нужное место.
Или тоже самое можно сделать в DopeSheet Action Editor но только не с кривыми, а с маркерами начали и окончания анимации - выделить все маркеры {A} и {G} для перемещения вдоль временной оси.